# RowNumber not working in Count Case

Tags: t-sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, case, row-number

I have this to count the number of book where status 'OnShelf'

```
select 

   BookTitleID, 
   BookTitle,
   CallNumber,
   FullName,
   count(case Status when 'OnShelf' then 1 else null end) AS CopiesOnShelves, 
from
(  
select 
       Book.BookTitleID,
       BookTitles.BookTitle,
       BookTitles.CallNumber,
       Book.Status,
       FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName,
From
    Book
        left outer join 
    BookTitles
        on BookTitles.BookTitleID = Book.BookTitleID 
        left outer join
    Authors
        on Authors.AuthorID = BookTitles.AuthorID   
) sub

Group By Callnumber, BookTitle, BookTitleID, FullName
```

Sample Output

```
BookTitleID    BookTitle      CallNumber    Fullname   CopiesOnShelves
1              sample         test          test       3
```

But when I include the row number in the select statement it give me wrong output

```
select 

   BookTitleID, 
   BookTitle,
   CallNumber,
   FullName,
   count(case Status when 'OnShelf' then 1 else null end) AS CopiesOnShelves, 
    r
from
(  
select 
       Book.BookTitleID,
       BookTitles.BookTitle,
       BookTitles.CallNumber,
       Book.Status,
       FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName,
       r = row_number() over (order by Book.BookTitleID) 
From
    Book
        left outer join 
    BookTitles
        on BookTitles.BookTitleID = Book.BookTitleID 
        left outer join
    Authors
        on Authors.AuthorID = BookTitles.AuthorID   

) sub

Group By Callnumber, BookTitle, BookTitleID, FullName, r
```

Sample Output

```
BookTitleID    BookTitle      CallNumber    Fullname   CopiesOnShelves  R
1              sample         test          test       1                1
1              sample         test          test       1                2
1              sample         test          test       1                3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   row_number() over (order by BookTitle) AS Row,
   BookTitleID, 
   BookTitle,
   CallNumber,
   FullName,
   count(case Status when 'OnShelf' then 1 else null end) AS CopiesOnShelves

from
(  
select 
       Book.BookTitleID,
       BookTitles.BookTitle,
       BookTitles.CallNumber,
       Book.Status,
       FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName

From
    Book
        left outer join 
    BookTitles
        on BookTitles.BookTitleID = Book.BookTitleID 
        left outer join
    Authors
        on Authors.AuthorID = BookTitles.AuthorID   ) sub
Group By Callnumber, BookTitle, BookTitleID, FullName
```

Got the right output but i got new problem [Row-Number in Between Sub Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677361/row-number-in-between-sub-query)

Comment: please mark this as the accepted answer so everyone else know it is complete - e.g. so others like me don't svae valuable time